# Insert records in datatable

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I have around 0.1 million records in `DataTable` with a default value columns `EdgeId` as 0

I am using following `linq` query to insert values in this table

```
foreach (IEdge ed in edCol)
{
    var row  = from r in dtRow.AsEnumerable()  
               where (((r.Field<string>("F1") == ed.Vertex1.Name) && 
                       (r.Field<string>("F2") == ed.Vertex2.Name)) || 
                      ((r.Field<string>("F1") ==ed.Vertex2.Name) &&
                       (r.Field<string>("F2") == ed.Vertex1.Name)))
               select r;

    foreach (DataRow rows in row)
    {
        row["EgdeId"]=ed.Id;
    }
}
```

Internal `foreach loop` takes most of the times to execute.

Is there any better way to insert the records in `DataTable` without using this `foreach loop` for each `DataRow`?

Comment: inside linq is a foreach loop.

Comment: What is lakh Kumar? we don't speak Indian :)

Comment: On top, you Need to at least TRY to make sense. Your Loop is not inserting anything. It is making a select. How much time? 1.5 Million rows is a lot of data to pull, if that is some seconds that may simply be your Network Speed.

Comment: It is taking almost 5-6 minutes

Comment: Please fix the horrible indenting to make it readable.

Comment: There are to many things called row or rows and they seem swapped in the inner for loop. I suspect ed is defined by the outer for loop, but it's missing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are iterating dtRow for each item in edCol. If the number of items in dtRow is large, and the number of matching items is comparatively low, you could preprocess dtRow to build an efficient mapping from (ed.Vertex1.Name, ed.Vertext2.Name) to list of rows. For instance Dictionary<Tuple<string,string>, List<DataRow>>.

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from r in dtRow.AsEnumerable()
            from ed in edCol
            let f1 = r.Field<string>("F1")
            let f2 = r.Field<string>("F2")
            let v1 = ed.Vertex1.Name
            let v2 = ed.Vertex2.Name
            where (f1 == v1 && f2 == v2) || 
                  (f1 == v2 && f2 == v1)
            select new { Row = r, EdgeId = ed.Id };

foreach(var item in query)
   item.Row["EgdeId"] = item.EdgeId;
```